# stored procedure functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know something about stored procedure functionality in sql.
I have approval history table, it will maintains the  data of all approvals (like present pending approval, who approved that)  whenever we have pending approval (approval is waiting for any approver)

Whenever in UI if we skip pending trading approval, it has to show system approved in comments.

The actual table is like this when all approval level are (current output)

```
Actionon    Action by       Action                      comments 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Date        apprvr name     approved                    
Date        apprvr name     PendingDA approval          da comments   
Date        apprvr name     Pending Ac approval         Ac comments
Date        apprvr name     Pending Trading approval    trading comment    
Date        apprvr name     Pending Finance  approval       finanace comments   
date        system                                      Batch has been created
```

if we skip any approvals (Unchecking in UI) for e.g. fin and AC skipped.
The current output

```
Actionon    Action by       Action                      comments 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Date        apprvr name     Pending Da apprval    
Date        apprvr name     Pending Trading  approval    trading comments   
date        system                                      Batch has been created
```

The table should be like this 
in first stage before approving trading

```
Actionon    Action by       Action                      comments 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Date        apprvr name     Pending Trading approval    
Date        apprvr name     Pending Finance  approval    system approved   
date        system                                      Batch has been created
```

after approving trading the table should be like this

```
Actionon    Action by       Action                      comments 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Date        apprvr name     PendingDA approval          
Date        apprvr name     Pending Ac approval         system approved
Date        apprvr name     Pending Trading approval    trading comment        
Date        apprvr name     Pending Finance  approval      system approved   
date        system                                      Batch has been created
```

can we achieve this by using stored procedure, or else any other way 
If it possible please help me how it can be done

Comment: Are you asking for a schema design or manipulate the workflow using a stored procedure? Whatever it is, you have to clarify your existing schema, existing data, expected behavior of stored procedure, and any sample data to clarify your needs.

Comment: your goal is not clear, as stated by @EmacsUser, but it looks like as a task for the presentation layer. maybe using a report you could achieve the formatting you are looking for. have a look at sql server reporting services

Comment: the existing behavior is when ever all approvals are there , that time from UI(java End) only it will insert data into the history table . @EmacsUser The expected results are posted in question But it showing inappropriate format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know something about stored procedure functionality in sql.

But the example you give is more attune with user interface design and nothing about stored procedures themselves. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding of what a stored procedure entails. Or you are asking something very esoteric that we are not able to quite understand your description. Or may be you are asking for a simple query, but that is not clear.

What might help is if you can re-state your needs in the terms of what an SQL Stored Procedure does. See this succinct [description of stored procedures](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx) to get you started.

If on the other hand, you are indeed asking about how to design an interface for your workflow, where for each state in the process, you need to capture the data at that state. Then as Paolo suggested above, you could start with [reporting services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms170246(v=sql.90).aspx), a feature of SQL Server 2008.

For example, when you ask:

> The table should be like this in first stage before approving trading

You can transform existing output into whatever you want with a simple report definition.

> after approving trading the table should be like this

You can have multiple report formats and trigger them for various stages, before approval, after approval, etc. Each report's spec follows each "should" in your question.